# What laws define resident and employee rights and protections on federal land, esp. administered by the National Park Service?

Tags: united-states, employment, jurisdiction, human-rights, us-federal-government

How do you look up which laws apply to people who live, work, operate businesses, etc., on a particular parcel of U.S. federal land, especially on land administered by the National Park Service?

How can residents or employees learn their rights and protections?

This dovetails closely with the following question from another user:
[Does San Francisco and California law have jurisdiction in the Presidio of San Francisco?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/85015/does-san-francisco-and-california-law-have-jurisdiction-in-the-presidio-of-san-f)

If you happen to find a source that answers this question for the Presidio of San Francisco, specifically, please include it!

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Different laws apply for different purposes.  Did you have a particular purpose in mind?  In general both state and federal laws apply, as they do pretty much everywhere, but on federal land there are additional federal laws that apply to federal land, and federal law applies to federal employees regardless of where they work.  A private concession in a federal facility could be subject to terms of the concession agreement.  A general answer is likely to miss a number of relevant circumstances.

Comment: Thanks, @phoog! San Francisco proper has a reputation for having codified strong protections for renters with things like rent control, eviction restrictions, and rent reductions for unreasonable periods without utilities/repairs. As far as I know, those do not apply next door in the Presidio, but how could residents learn what rules and rights do apply? Re: employment, do California rules about things like at-will employment apply, or is that a different system?

Comment: Are there residential rental properties on the grounds of the Presidio (which, by the way, isn't next door to SF but is part of it)?  If there are no such properties then the question of whether SF tenant protections apply there is irrelevant.  But, in general, because the Presidio is part of California and part of San Francisco, you can expect that California labor law and San Francisco landlord and tenant regulations both apply.

Comment: @Phoog that's really the point of this whole question, isn't it? People who live and work there don't know whose rules go, but it's probably federal, and they don't know where to find the applicable rules. There are 4000 residents and 200 businesses and nonprofits based in the Presidio, which is a former military property now owned by the National Park Service and administered by a trust. People there get told that San Francisco laws don't apply.